# Java, JDBC messing up by multithreading?

Tags: java, jdbc

I am getting ~20'000 rows out of a database with JDBC in Java, Eclipse IDE.

I go through the result set step by step (ordered by id). Every row contains information about its previous and succeeding "identifier" (unique string of a row). So for every row I check if the chain is broken or not, b/c of whatever reason.

My approach beneath works, and don't quote me on that, but it seems it works better for the first 10'000 than for the following. Error quota is 335 for 19'999 entries. I checked with my own eyes if the reported errors are in accordance with reality, but they are definitely not, at least for 1 error.

Do I miss something important? Why does this happen? It almost looks like it is the result of parallelization, multithreading, etc.?

```
int i = 0;
String actualprevious = "", previous = "", next = "";
boolean first = true; // we can't check if the first is in line because it is the first
int errors = 0;

while (rs.next())
{
    if (i%10000==0) { System.out.println("Checked "+(i/10000)+" myriads."); } // inform
    String current = rs.getString("identifier");
                
    if (!current.equals(next)) { System.out.println("Current is: "+current); System.out.println("Expected "+next+" to be next, but "+current+" is."); errors++; } // inform
    // ignore: Document doc = Jsoup.parse(rs.getString("source"));
    next = rs.getString("next");
    if (next==null) { System.out.println("There is no next listed in row "+current+"."); errors++; } // inform
    
    previous = rs.getString("previous");
    if (!first && !actualprevious.equals(previous)) { System.out.println("Expected "+actualprevious+" to be listed as previous, but "+previous+" was in document "+current+"."); errors++; } // inform
    
    actualprevious = current;
    i++; 
    first = false;
}
```

Comment: Unless you access the `ResultSet` `rs` someplace else, this is thread safe. But I have not really understood what exactly the problem is. Could you post us some lines of data and where the output is faulty? And maybe set your info print to 1:1 instead of 1:10000 and then stop the system (conditional breakpoint) if it's in a bad state, so you can check. This here with `String`s all over the place cries for problems with the `String`s themselves, like capitalization or spaces somewhere...

Comment: It is probably the filling of the records, previous, current and next, that fails. It should have been done with a generated key, and ResultSet.getGeneratedKeys. Next and previous might be error prone too.

Comment: Also, with `if (next==null)` you check for null but not other invalid Strings like empty String or a String only containing spaces etc... Maybe that bugs it out?

Comment: what is the sql? in particular, the ORDER BY?

Comment: There is nothing in the pasted code that is wrong. You're asking us: "Does JDBC randomly return gobbledygook". The answer is the rather obvious: "No". It's something about the data in that database, your query, or code not pasted. There is no `--actually-work-properly` switch you're missing.

Comment: The question is not easy to narrow down, I have to spend more time on identifying the problem.